# When hover at an image, will reduce the opacity and add text

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity, line-breaks

As can see at jsfiddle, When hover at the image, opacity of the image will reduce and text will be added to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/QPW27/12/

I am having problem here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

When I hover over the image, the image does not appear to be stable, the opacity will reduce and increase, even thought the mouse has not left the image.

I would like to break the title to two lines: first line- Pan, second line-Mee.
I tried \n  but could not achieve it. Is there a way?

```
<body>       
  <div id="img" class="img"> 
     <img  class="onclick" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d561d41394ff0d5d0715b2695c3dcf0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" 
     title="PanMee" alt="PanMee"   
     onclick="bigImage(1)"  style=" width:205px;height:160px; "/> 
  </div> 
</body>

var t;
$('div.img img').hover(function(){  
  var textTopPosition = $(this).position().top+17;  
  var textLeftPosition = $(this).position().left+6; 
  t = $('<div/>')
      .css({top:textTopPosition})
      .css({left:textLeftPosition})
      .text($(this).attr('title'))
      .appendTo($(this).parent());  
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.3);
  },function(){
     $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
     $(t).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QPW27/123/)

Try this

```
    var t;
    $('div.img img').hover(function(){  
      var textTopPosition = $(this).position().top+17;  
      var textLeftPosition = $(this).position().left+6; 
      t = $('<div/>')
          .css({top:textTopPosition})
          .css({left:textLeftPosition})
          .text($(this).attr('title'))
      .appendTo($(this).parent());  
      $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.3);
    });  

    $('div.img').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).find("img").fadeTo('fast',1);
         $(this).find("div").remove();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you know how to break the title to two lines: first line- Pan, second line-Mee.
I tried \n but could not achieve it.

Comment: Whenever I hover at the image for a longer time, it will show a yellow text, with <br> in between, as shown in  http://i.stack.imgur.com/SouyW.png. Do you know if there is any way to not show the yellow text?